# How can I preview a Compose view when it need a parameter in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I can run Code A in Android Studio, I hope to preview UI when I'm  designing, so I added Code B to Code A.

But Code B can't work, why? How can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val handleMeter by viewModels<HandleMeter>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SoundMeterTheme {       
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting(handleMeter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter) {
  ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    SoundMeterTheme {
        val handleMeter by viewModels<HandleMeter>()
        Greeting(handleMeter)
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably see this in logs: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview. You neen to pass viewmodel's methods and properties (or fake empty copies of) to your composable instead of viewmodel itsef.

Comment: Thanks! How can I to pass viewmodel's methods and properties (or fake empty copies of)  ?

Comment: Its called state hoisting, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689843/jetpack-compose-state-hoisting-previews-and-viewmodels-best-practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.
Preview does not support creating ViewModels and NavHost yet, for our bad.
But what you can do instead is to use a fake data or a static data into ui, until the design finish and when you are ready to actually run it, replace the static data with the view model data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dagger and hilt to inject the view model constructor and then call up the hilt view model in the preview e.g.

```
@HiltViewModel
class DataFieldsViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {
```

Then in your preview code for your composable

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewDataFieldsScreen() {
    DataFieldsScreen(
        navController = rememberNavController(),
        viewModel = hiltViewModel()
    )
}
```